# Changing the Handling Charge in Exp-resso Store

Tags: expresso-store

The per-item handling surcharge is based on items in the order. "If the user purchases multiple items, this number will be multiplied by the item quantity, and displayed in the {order_handling} variable. (from Exp-resso Store docs)"

Is there a way to make this handling charge per order not per Item? Running 1.6x Exp-resso Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your shipping gateway but something along the lines of this will work for the UPS gateway. To add the price to the UPS plugin you will want to open up the shipping plugin system/expressionengine/third_party/store/libraries/store_shipping/store_shipping_ups.php scroll down towards the bottom you should see something along the lines of

```
return (float)$xml->ShipmentRate->TotalCharges->MonetaryValue;
```

you will want to change that to

```
return (float)$xml->ShipmentRate->TotalCharges->MonetaryValue +4;
```

That should then add $4 to the calculated price of your shipping.

Comment: I am not using a shipping plugin. This is a series of tickets, they can buy 2 or 3 series and the mailing and handling is include in the one fee charge. That fee would be $14.00.

Comment: In that case I would setup the default Shipping Plugin and assign a flat rate of $14 to all orders.